# Python error PermissionError: [WinError 32]

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo esto de programar en Python, pero me ha surgido un error en mi código y no logro solucionarlo:

```
if existe:
    with open(CARPETA + nombre_anterior + EXTENSION,'w') as archivo:
        #Resto de los campos
        nombre_contacto = input('Agrega el Nuevo Nombre: \r\n')
        telefono_contacto = input('Agrega el Nuevo Teléfono:\r\n')
        categoria_contacto = input('Agrega el Nuevo Categoría:\r\n')
        #Instanciar
        contacto = Contacto(nombre_contacto, telefono_contacto, categoria_contacto)
        #Escribir en el archvio
        archivo.write('Nombre: ' + contacto.nombre + '\r\n')
        archivo.write('Teléfono: ' + contacto.telefono + '\r\n')
        archivo.write('Categoría: ' + contacto.categoria + '\r\n')

        #Renombrar el archivo
        os.rename(CARPETA + nombre_anterior + EXTENSION, CARPETA + nombre_contacto + EXTENSION)
        #Mostrar un mensaje de éxito
        print('\r\n Contacto creado correctamente \r\n')

else:
    print('Ese contacto no existe')
```

por lo tantom no he terminado mi ejercicio ya que el error se me presenta de esta manera:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\3D Objects\yop\16-proyecto.py", line 119, in <module>
   app()
 File "C:\Users\Daniel\3D Objects\yop\16-proyecto.py", line 31, in app
  editar_contacto()
 File "C:\Users\Daniel\3D Objects\yop\16-proyecto.py", line 65, in editar_contacto
   os.rename(CARPETA + nombre_anterior + EXTENSION, CARPETA + nombre_contacto + EXTENSION)
 PermissionError: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado 
  por otro proceso: 'contactos/loco.txt' -> 'contactos/gip.txt'
```

Espero alguien me pudiese ayudar a entender mi error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes renombrar el archivo porque lo tienes abierto. El bloque `with` abre el archivo y hace cosas, y solo cierra el archivo al salir de ese bloque. La solución es renombrar el archivo fuera del bloque with (cuando ya se ha cerrado el archivo).

```
with open(CARPETA + nombre_anterior + EXTENSION,'w') as archivo:
    # todo esto está dentro del with...
    archivo.write('Categoría: ' + contacto.categoria + '\r\n')
# Esto ya está fuera, así que renombramos el archivo
os.rename(CARPETA + nombre_anterior + EXTENSION, CARPETA + nombre_contacto + EXTENSION)
```

Las identaciones son muy importantes en python. Asegurate siempre de que tu código esté en la columna adecuada.